# JMeter - passing jdbc response code to a java request?

Tags: java, jdbc, jmeter

I have a scenario where I should pass the JDBC response code as a parameter to a Java request.

I tried using the variable name and result variable name. I am not able to achieve it. The response I get is `${test}` in java request.

Comment: This question is not really answerable with only two sentences and virtually no code.  Please edit your question, include the relevant code, and point out what the problem is.

Comment: I have not done much of a code here . I have ajdbc config  and jdbc request . On querying i have 1 column of data . This data needs to be passed as a parameter in java request . I am able to pass this for one value from the database , but unable to iterate it bcos I am not sure how to use the same varaible name or result variable name in a java request parameter

Comment: Do you have any specs, e.g. API docs?  Kind of hard to guess at what some servlet expects I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer JMeter Variable from the Java Request sampler like:

```
JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables().get("test"); // if the variable is a String

JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables().getObject("test"); // if the variable is something else
```

References:

- [JMeterContextService](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContextService.html)
- [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html)
- [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)
- [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter)